# how to delete email address from table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I wanted to delete the email address of the customer in phpmyadmin, using php and html. The delete button is working, but it doesn't delete the email address at all.

I'm still new in learning php language. So, there might be some parts I might have done wrong.

I made 3 pages; account.php, deleteemail.php and delete.php

This is the php code for account.php

```
<?php 

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("eib_clicks") or die("Cannot connect to database");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_ai WHERE username='$user' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            Print "<tr>";

                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['username'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['name'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['address'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['secondaddress'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center"><a href="addaddress.php?username='. $row['username'] .'">add</a> </td>';
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['email'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center"><a href="editemail.php?username='. $row['username'] .'">edit</a> </td>';
                Print '<td align="center"><a href="deleteemail.php?username='. $row['username'] .'">delete</a> </td>';
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['type'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center">'. $row['public'] . "</td>";
                Print '<td align="center"><a href="editpublic.php?username='. $row['username'] .'">edit</a> </td>';
            Print "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
```

This one works just fine.

Php code for deleteemail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']){
}
else{
    header("location:account.php");
}
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$id_exists = false;
?>
```

Second part of the code;

```
<?php

                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db("eib_clicks") or die("Cannot connect to database");
                $query = mysql_query("Select * from customer_ai Where username='$user'");
                $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($count > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        Print "<tr>";
                            Print '<td align="center">'. $row['email'] . "</td>";



                        Print "</tr>";
                    }
                }

            ?>
```

Third part of the code;

```
<?php

        Print '
        <a href="delete.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" role="button" onclick="myFunction('.$row['username'] .')">Delete</a>

        ';


        ?>
```

I add script in this page too;

```
<script>
    function myFunction(username)
    {
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this email?");
    if(r==true)
        {
            window.location.assign("deleteemail.php?username=" + username);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Lastly php code for delete.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']){
    }
    else{
        header("location:homepage.php");
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("eib_clicks") or die("Cannot connect to database");

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM account_ai WHERE $email=['email']");

        header("location: account.php");
    }
?>
```

I tried everything on the delete.php but nothing works. The rest of the codes works fine. I used $row['id'] but it deletes the whole row. I only wanted to delete the email address not the whole row. Please help me.

This is how my customer_ai table looks like;

[table for customer_ai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCuSX.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to remove the email while leaving the rest of the row alone or are you trying to delete the entire row if it matches the email?  You description says the former, but your code says the latter.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the email and leaving the rest of it alone. I was using the codes that my lecturer gave me.

Comment: You want to update then, not delete.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is UPDATE, not DELETE.  You want to set the value of the email to NULL. `UPDATE customer_ai SET email = NULL WHERE username = some_username`  Replace some_username with your php.

Edit: I noticed your code has acccount_ai, but your screenshot is customer_ai so I used customer_ai.

Answer (score 2):

Just paste this:

**delete.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['user']){
    }
    else{
        header("location:homepage.php");
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
    {
          $username = $_GET['username'];
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("eib_clicks") or die("Cannot connect to database");

        mysql_query("UPDATE account_ai SET email = '' WHERE username = '$username'");

        header("location: account.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: please do not give answers that add more security vulnerabilities to OP's code.

Comment: do you mean to tell me that you use `mysql_*` in your own projects?

Comment: So warn the OP not to use `mysql_*` ! simple!!

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE` deletes a complete row. Instead use `UPDATE` and set the column to `NULL`.

```
UPDATE account_ai SET email = NULL WHERE username = $username
```

**If the `$username` is a user-supplied value, be sure to escape it, otherwise you will risk a SQL injection.**

Be aware that `mysql_connect` is deprecated, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Maybe you take a look at this [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). Pay attention to the *Prepared statements. Protection from SQL injections* chapter.

Answer (score 1):

in delete.php you could try like below:

```
$email_address =!empty($_GET['username'])?$_GET['username']:false;

if($email_address){

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM account_ai WHERE email='{$email_address}'  ");
 }
```

Comment: please do not give answers that add more security vulnerabilities to OP's code.